# Picking up a used MSI All in One - what quick tests can be run on it?

Tags: hardware-failure, dead-pixel

[This](https://www.msi.com/All-in-One-PC/Gaming-24GE-2QE.html) is the specific model in question. It looks good, and the price is right. The seller has also offered to allow me to test it before handing over the money. However, I don't think he'd be very happy to wait for something like memtest while some stranger stands in his house (I know I wouldn't). What are some good quick tests I can run that weed out common problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a broard question, as there are many tests you could run.

The first thing I would do though is to run [CPUz](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) (or an equivalent).

This allows you to do a couple of things - the first being to verify that the hardware (CPU etc) is as advertised.  It also has a CPU benchmark that you can run to provide a quick assessment that it's running correctly.

Memory isn't a quick thing to test, beyond confirming that all the dimms appear to the system and the full capacity is shown. To fully test it, you would have to run memtest.  If there does turn out to be an issue though, RAM isn't typically very expensive to replace.

To check that the HDDs are healthy, run the following in `cmd`:

```
wmic
```

then

```
diskdrive get status
```

This will report any SMART issues.

There are a couple of web based GPU benchmarks that you could run to confirm that the graphics card could take some stress, [BMark](https://www.wirple.com/bmark/) and [OortOnline](http://oortonline.gl/) come up as the top results in a google search, but I haven't tried them myself.

For dead pixels, there are a number of tests online, like [this one](http://jasonfarrell.com/misc/deadpixeltest.php) that change the screen to various colours to make them stand out.